# Function Notations for Derivatives and Composites

Tags: functions, derivatives

Given that iterating $f$ $m$ times are written like
\begin{align*}
f^m(x)=(f\circ f\circ \ldots \circ f)(x)
\end{align*}
and $n$th derivative is written like
\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(x)=f\underbrace{''^{\ldots}{'}}_{n~'s}(x)
\end{align*}

Is there a way to represent the $n$th derivative of $f^m(x)$ in a single expression and vice versa?

Comment: $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f^m$?

Comment: When the humble superscript can be understood in more than one way (as with your cases and the more common exponent/power), it is best to give your Readers the benefit of *defining* how you use notation, e.g. explain the subtle distinction between $f^{n}$ and $f^{(n)}$ in your own terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists very easy way.

We can denote n-th derivative of $f$ as $\frac {d^n}{dx^n}f$.

So...

$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f^m(x)
$$

can be the answer.

Comment: oh wait... how did I forget that classic $\frac{d}{dx}$ notation lol